# Get outlook recurrence pattern of a event in iCal format using C#

Tags: android, icalendar, rfc2445, outlook-calendar, rfc5545

I am developing a system which extract the `outlook calendar data` and save it on android device calendar. Up to now all other outlook data are extracted and saved successfully. Now I need to create recurrence rule (`rrule`). Because android device calendar use to save recurrence pattern as a rule which is mentioned as `rfc5545` standard. So how can I extract outlook recurrence pattern as a `rule (like iCal format)`.

In briefly, I need to get recurrence pattern of the Outlook calendar event as like this

```
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20000131T140000Z;BYMONTH=1

**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the Office `RecurrencePattern Object`  [see msft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211012%28v=office.11%29.aspx) which represents the pattern of incidence of recurring appointments for the associated `AppointmentItem` object.

the object has `RecurrenceType (olRecursDaily, olRecursMonthly, ...)` which have themselves properties `(Interval, DayOfWeekMask, DayOfMonth, ...)`

with this information you can build the string defined by rfc5545.

one example implementation is available see : [sourceforge otlook2ical](http://sourceforge.net/projects/outlook2ical/files/outlook2ical/v1.04/)